# Access denied when generated a random number for path to upload images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, carrierwave

Here is what I have in the avatar uploader

I had the method like this

```
def store_dir
  "12345"
end
```

This works fine .. and the url is https://shijokes-testing-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/12345/Simple_and_beautyful.png

But when changed the method to

```
def store_dir
 "#{rand(1000).to_s}"
end
```

The url is this

https://shijokes-testing-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/347/Simple_and_beautyful.png

And I get

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>50399D3AF94097F8</RequestId>
<HostId>
I5Z/LjqbkF+xpskz0cqTtz1wDMb9qZ3IuvrH9Eni2g6fJqkuoK3a+lVAP5zMRm8bdNhIT8KgugQ=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Comment: What is the bucket policy on `shijokes-testing-assets` and/or the permissions assigned to the credentials being used to access Amazon S3?

Comment: Yes all permissions are there, that is why I am able to use the url https://shijokes-testing-assets.s3.amazonaws.com/12345/Simple_and_beautyful.png

Comment: Using a random no. in `store_dir` means it gives a new no. everytime its called. My guess is Carrierwave invokes this method in `uploader.store!(my_file)` as well as `uploaded.url` calls, hence the problem. Best is to generate and save that no. somewhere else and then use it